# Foley techniques for fat hands!

Tags: foley

Hey all,

I am foleying a scene with a very... shall we say robust character. I want to highlight his heft with the hand foley that I am doing. Does anyone have any good techniques for thickening things up? Either on the record or mix side?

My first inclination is to just do a bit of light pitch shifting, but would love to hear any other thoughts on ways to make things sound a bit thicker and grosser.

Thanks,
Jesse

Answer (score 2):

What types of things is this person handling?

Because, instead of using those exact items, think of something slightly heavier to record with. For example, a smaller tea-cup being substituted by a larger, heavier tea-cup on the foley stage to move around with.

I think in addition to the foley being large, also make his weight shift floorboards, toss in large footsteps and deeper impact sit-downs, and sell the weight that way.

And one thing I've done to make a larger person sound more "disgusting" is replacing out his breathing with more wheezing and lip smack sounds. Think of that Super Bowl commercial with the world's most famous extra making out with the super-model - they added in some really disgusting mouth noise and lip smacks on that smooch. Here's a link:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o-3j4-4N3Ng

Comment: Great ideas all around. The character does a lot of driving so I will be mostly focusing on his hands on the wheel. I'll have to find a larger prop that fits the bill. Thanks jay and Utopia

Answer (score 0):

How about using lots of hand cream to make your hands more moist, sweaty? Or for the extreme gross factor, chicken breasts or steaks (be sure to disinfect afterwards).

Of course, you haven't described what he is doing with his hands so hard to say what it is you need to achieve. Is it strictly weight or would the wet idea work?

Pitch shifting, sub harmonic layering or Eqing the lower frequencies could work.

Comment: Utopia nailed it.